# Fingerprint data encryption/decryption?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, fingerprint, face-id

Is it posible to encrypt/decrypt data with fingerprint/faceid?

I know I cannot get the data of fingerprint/faceid but could i generate a key/hash from fingerprint/faceid user's input?

Comment: No, there is no way to gain access to any data related to the biometrics. All you get is a true/false when you request biometric authentication.  You could store a key in the keychain and protect it with biometrics but that key could be unlocked by any enrolled finger, not a specific finger.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking about both iOS and Android. Here's the answer for iOS:

Yes, this is possible! To make this work, you need to store your secret in the iOS keychain, and make it a requirement to pass biometric authentication (TouchID/FaceID) for you to get the secret out again.

Not sure if React Native supports this without dropping to native code, but you need to use `SecAccessControl` (part of the keychain API) along with the `LocalAuthentication` framework to interact with the biometric prompts. Here's some documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/accessing_keychain_items_with_face_id_or_touch_id

https://www.raywenderlich.com/236-how-to-secure-ios-user-data-the-keychain-and-biometrics-face-id-or-touch-id

Note: The keychain will handle encryption/decryption for you. You also don't get any biometric data back, just a pass/fail. You don't need that to be able to do what you're asking, though.